# Integrate java program with SOAPUI groovy

Tags: java, methods, soapui, program-entry-point

I have a java program which with main method and its accessing a URL and saving a the data required from the webpage into variables. I need to integrate this program with SOAP UI. Purpose: I need to use those variables to set property values in SOAP UI. Any pointers would help.
I want to use groovy script and access this java program and use the variables in derived int he java program.

```
public class DownloadPage {

            /**
            * @param args
            * @throws IOException 
             */
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
String email="test@email.com"
String name="Name";
}
```

Comment: Do you have the source code or just the bytecode for your Java program?

Comment: I can't share the actual code. Say I have a java program which has main method and a class where I have get and set methods. I set the value in the main method and I want to access The get method. All this I want to do it in groovy.

Comment: Right. :( If you have the source, then copy-paste it into a Groovy Script step and go nuts. If you have the jar, the copy-paste it into $SOAPUI_HOME/bin/ext and start calling methods from a Groovy Script step.

Comment: I do have the jar. But since it has the main method would I have to execute it and then use the methods? I tried what you have told above but didn't work.

Comment: So you want to call *some* methods in *some* jar. That is very difficult to give a definitive answer.

Comment: I was able to call the jar from groovy step in SOAP UI and access the data elements.